# I want to add a scroll property as my form is rendering as a seperate component inside a modal which is a sperate component in itself

Tags: css, reactjs

As my employee form got too big for the screen. so, I want to add scroll property to my modal content inside of which the form is rendered as the form as too many fields and cannot alter any of them.

So, Can you fix the scroll problem for me. Thanks!

Here My code

```
import React from 'react';
import modalCSS from '../styles/modal.module.css';
import PurchasesForm from './forms/PurchasesForm';
import SalesForm from './forms/SalesForm';
import ExpensesForm from "./forms/ExpensesForm";
import InventoryForm from './forms/InventoryForm';
import StocksForm from './forms/StocksForm';
import EmployeeForm from './forms/EmployeeForm';
import SalaryForm from './forms/SalaryForm';
import LedgerForm from './forms/LedgerForm';

function Modal({ prop, closeModal, propObject, setPropObject, operation, updateItem }) {

    return (
        <div className={modalCSS.container}>
            <div className={modalCSS.modalBox}>
                
                <div className={modalCSS.header}>
                    <h1 className={modalCSS.title}>Add {prop}</h1>
                    <img src='/images/cross.svg' alt='cross-mark' className={modalCSS.crossBtn} onClick={() => closeModal()}/>
                </div>

                <div className={modalCSS.modalContent}>
                    {prop === "Sale" && <SalesForm sales={propObject} setSales={setPropObject} operation={operation} updateItem={updateItem} />}
                    {prop === "Purchase" && <PurchasesForm purchase={propObject} setPurchase={setPropObject} operation={operation} updateItem={updateItem} />}
                    {prop === "Expense" && <ExpensesForm expense={propObject} setExpense={setPropObject} operation={operation} updateItem={updateItem} />}
                    {prop === "Inventory" && <InventoryForm inventory={propObject} setInventory={setPropObject} operation={operation} updateItem={updateItem} />}
                    {prop === "Stock" && <StocksForm stock={propObject} setStock={setPropObject} operation={operation} updateItem={updateItem} />}
                    {prop === "Employee" && <EmployeeForm employee={propObject} setEmployee={setPropObject} operation={operation} updateItem={updateItem} />}
                    {prop === "Salary" && <SalaryForm />}
                    {prop === "Ledger" && <LedgerForm />}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Modal
```

Here's the CSS file

modal.module.css

```
.container{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    z-index: 999;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.modalBox{
    height: fit-content;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.header{
    padding: 1%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    /* background-color: #F0F0F0; */
}

.crossBtn{
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modalContent{
    height: 100%;
    /* overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden; */
    padding: 1%;
}
```

This is what happening when i put height: fit-content; in modalBox class

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYDho.png)

If set `height: 80%;` in `modalBox` and set `height: fit-content;` in `modalContent` class then this happens

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrO1K.png)

As you can see here is that modal stays good and form still overflows still after setting the overflow property.

So, suggest a solution keeping that in mind that i want to keep the height: fit-content in modalBox class as i am using the modal for different classes. so i can fit the forms of different sizes in there.

Help Me with this.. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can add fix height and overflow-y scroll in this way,

Add this CSS in **modalContent** class.

**Make height as per your requirement.**

```
height: 500px;
overflow-y: auto;
```

It might work, Thanks.

Comment: It worked......Thanks bro!!!!!!!